# Cant store the image to the database using php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to upload an image in my database from HTML form. I have written the PHP code and I have an error message

```
     <form action="login.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         user<input type="text" name="user_name1"  required />
           password<input type="password" name="password1" required />
             Email<input type="email" name="email11" required />     
Upload any image you want<input type="file" name="image">
  <input  class="submit" type="submit" name="submit2" value="sign up"/>

            </form>
```

and this is the PHP code

```
  <?php

     if(array_key_exists('submit2',$_POST))
{

$user=$_POST['user_name1'];
$pass=$_POST['password1'];
$email=$_POST['email11'];
$image=addcslashes($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$image_name=addcslashes($_FILES['image']['name']);
$image2=file_get_contents($image);
$image3=base64_encode($image2);
$query9="insert into login  values('$user','$pass','$email','$image3','$image_name')";
if(mysqli_query($conn,$query9))

echo "Insert is successful";

else

echo "Error ".$query9."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);



}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

This is the error I get after executing the code

> Warning: addcslashes() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in

Comment: You are missing one parameter. Check the documentation here: https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.addcslashes.php

Comment: As the warning suggests, the second parameter (`$charlist`) is required for [addcslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addcslashes.php) It may not do exactly what you want, but regular [addslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) might work

Comment: Storing files in database is not the best practice. Better save file on server on specific folder and just save the Path to the folder in database. However, inserting as BLOB in database will store files in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [addcslashes](https://secure.php.net/manual/fr/function.addcslashes.php) which requires 2 parameters, the first being the string, and the second, a list of characters you want to escape.

I believe you want to use [addslashes](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) which will return your string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped.